# How to create multiple AWS API Gateway Stage paths using CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I am attempting to create AWS API Gateway stages that look like this:

[image: Image from console creasted API Gateway]

Without success, using the following CloudFormation code, I am attempting to create these stages:

```
ConnectApiGwResource:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties: 
      ParentId: !GetAtt ConnectRestApi.RootResourceId
      PathPart: sendmessage
      RestApiId: !Ref ConnectRestApi

ConnectDeployment:
    DependsOn: ConnectApiGwMethod
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment'
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref ConnectRestApi
      Description: Connect deployment

  Dev:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    Properties:
      StageName: dev
      Description: Dev Stage
      RestApiId: !Ref ConnectRestApi
      DeploymentId: !Ref ConnectDeployment
      MethodSettings:
        - ResourcePath: /process-twilio-message
          HttpMethod: POST
        - ResourcePath: /sendmessage
          HttpMethod: GET
  v1:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    Properties:
      StageName: v1
      Description: v1 Stage
      RestApiId: !Ref ConnectRestApi
      DeploymentId: !Ref ConnectDeployment
      MethodSettings:
        - ResourcePath: /sendmessage
          HttpMethod: POST
```

What I get with the above CloudFormation code is the /process-twilio-message path is missing from the dev stage. Also, notice I put GET as the HttpMethod for /sendmessage, but the path shows POST as the Method in the console.

What code changes are required to create the Stages shown in the image?

Answer (score 0):

First off I would encourage you to use [AWS SAM](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/) to build serverless applications if you like CloudFormation. AWS SAM is built on top pf CloudFormation and reduces the amount of code required.

Secondly, if you need multiple versions of the same API in production, the best practice is to use CustomDomains and base path mapping. [Here is a blog that explains it](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-multiple-segments-in-amazon-api-gateway-base-path-mapping/). The blog includes an example application.

For more on AWS SAM there is a series called [Sessions with Sam](https://s12d.com/sws) that helps how AWS SAM simplifies developing serverless applications.

Full disclosure, I work for AWS and produced the content in these links.